# Can I ask about how to use an app in the main site?

Tags: support

If I don't understand how to use a app or certain feature of an app(because UI of some apps are not intuitive enough to understand), can I ask that [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com)?If not which stackexchange site is appropriate for asking this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are having a problem in performing a task with an app, you can seek help on our [main site](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). It is within the scope of our main site.

Per [What topics can I ask about here?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in Help Center:

> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - **Using a particular app on your Android device**
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device
>
> then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>